# Invariant sets of 2 by 2 linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dynamical-systems

Suppose that we have a $2\times 2$ linear mapping given by a matrix $A$.
There are three cases: 1) the eigenvalues $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$ are real, 2) there is only one real eigenvalue $\lambda$, 3) there are two complex eigenvalues satisfying $\lambda_1 = \overline{\lambda_2}$.

In each case I would like to derive the exact equations of the curves that are invariant under this mapping. For instance, in the first case, when $1 > |\lambda_1| > |\lambda_2|$, these curves should be exponential functions, but how to derive the exact equations for them? And how to do the analogous for all other cases? I would just like to use elementary linear algebra here.

Thank you very much for some help.

Comment: @JohnB The OP asked about the discrete-time DS given by the iterates of $A$, not about the system of linear ODEs.

Comment: A hint (at least for 1)): First, make a linear change of coordinates so that the matrix $A$ in the new coordinates is diagonal.  Then find a power function $f$ such that $(\lambda_1 x,\lambda_2 f(x))=(\lambda_1 x, f(\lambda_1 x))$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is clear that one needs to use the diagonal form, similarly in the case 2) the Jordan normal form. However, how to find this function. If $(x, y)$ is a vector, then $A(x,y) = (\lambda_1 x, \lambda_2 y)$. But how to see the dependence of $y$ on $x$?

Comment: One must have that each point lying on the graph of $f$ is taken by the action of $A$ to a point lying on the graph of $f$.  And I gave you a hint: look for $f$ among the power functions.

Comment: Ok, finally, I have that $f$ must satisfy the functional equation $\lambda_2 f(x) = f(\lambda_1 x)$. The solution is $x^{\frac{\log{\lambda_2}}{\log{\lambda_1}}}$.

Comment: @JohnB Are you serious?

Comment: @JohnB You accused me of plagiarism, and after less than one minute deleted your comment.

Comment: @JohnB "annoy"?